# Whenever I run npm install in my terminal, I get "cb() never called"

Tags: npm-install

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JOVANNE DELA ROSA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-16T20_58_48_839Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try reading the log as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1):

When we install a node packages from `package.json` file and `package-lock.json` file is corrupted due to some reasons like node.js version is updated to the latest, we will see an error like this in our terminal.

To fix this error, first delete the `package-lock.json` file and run the following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Now, try to install your packages using the `npm install` command.

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\JOVANNE DELA ROSA\zippelin-merchant-web/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\JOVANNE DELA ROSA\zippelin-merchant-web\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JOVANNE DELA ROSA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-21T02_30_17_434Z-debug.log

Comment: Hi Simran, that worked for me. Just deleting the package-lock.json and launching npm install again fixed my problem. Thanks! I don't  really know if it is a good practice to upload this file to the repo, as gives some problems regarding the install is done on linux or windows, and with differetn versions of node.

Comment: @rtrujillor yes you should upload this file to your online repo. Because your node packages will install on the basis of packages mentioned in the file.
e.g. You or someone else clone/download your project on another laptop and the first time he needs to run "npm install". If there is no "package-lock.json" file, that "npm install" command don't know what to install. So it's iimportant to keep in online repo.